# Html / Css link problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

Okay, so finally got the business site finished today; however the index page I created to direct people to the relevant webpage has stopped working. In Internet Explorer it shows and highlights links but only when viewing it locally. The Css and HTML can be located here (testing.coolcosy.com).
Thankyou!
Peter

P.S I know my Css isn't tidy, I am really not cut out for web design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Urls like "Community.CoolCosy.Com" should start with http:// unless it's a folder name in your current location.

Fixed it for you taking in account all answers: http://jsfiddle.net/GfCjG/1/

Comment: It's completely fine to put links in headers.

Comment: Wow! Cheers for the response guys! I am blown away with how quickly you guys fixed it! Drop me an e-mail if any of you ever need a favor! peter@coolcosy.com

Answer (score 0):

your div id "wrapper" is covering the html links. Im no designer but a  quick fix would be put a z-index of -1 on the wrapper

infact you have two elements which have the ID of wrapper - this isnt standards compliant I believe but It the one wrapping the footer that is causing you trouble

Comment: I doubt z-index would help here, as that only applies to positioned elements which are not used here.

Comment: Firebug displayed the bottom wrapper as having position relative on it! Hence the quick fix - probs not the right fix though

Answer (score 0):

You have two divs with the same id "wrapper". This is not allowed, by definition there must be no elements with the same ID in the DOM. Anyway the second one (which contains the footer) is covering your links.

You should stile it differently to avoid it overlapping your links.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers allready mentioned it, but I'd like to summarize and give some additional hints:

First off, especially since you claim your self not being cut out for web design, always [validate your code](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://testing.coolcosy.com/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) to correct the most obvious errors.

Your actual problem that the second "wrapper" overlaps the links. That is because you are floating the elements with the links, which removes them from the flow of the page. You are correctly using "clear: both" on the footer to "move" the footer after the floats, but this leaves the surrounding "wrapper" to still cover the floats. You need to put the `clear:both`on the wrapper instead - but first make sure you get rid of the duplicate IDs.